# Chromium in Docker throws "Failed to create shared context for virtualization"

Tags: docker, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I have a debian-based Docker container (the host machine is on Windows 10). It has Chromium installed via `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends chromium`. 
When I run a test command:

```
/usr/bin/chromium --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --hide-scrollbars --window-size="1920,1080" --default-background-color=00000000 --hide-scrollbars --disable-features=NetworkService --virtual-time-budget=20000 --screenshot=/tmp/screenshot.png https://www.google.com
```

it complains saying:

```
[0916/202547.786718:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(398)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization.
```

I'm getting the correct screenshot despite the error, but I'd want to get rid of this alert anyway. 
Googling didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, my answer isn't for chromium directly. But for cef (CefGlue), which based on it. I run on linux without gpu (server).

I got exactly same error on cef version 76.1.13.

Thanks to https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome/issues/36#issuecomment-534392761

The reason is flag "--disable-software-rasterizer". 
I used it with old version of cef. But for now it cause error.

I see, that you doesn't use this flag, but may be you skip it when ask question?